# How to move text up when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new at jQuery and I need help. I want to make the text move up and static box slowly disappear when you scroll website down.

Something like this: http://eliastinchon.com/

```css
p,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 3000px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #282828;
}
#slide {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#static {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p id="slide">Some text</p>
  <!-- This slideUp when scrolling down -->
  <div id="static">This box is static</div>
```

Comment: There is [**FIDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/dzket0tj/) without jQuery, because my code doesn´t work. Thank you <3

Comment: add code to question not as a comment. and show us what you have tried regardless if it works or not

Comment: The effect that you are describing is called parallax. You do not need jQuery for that, this can be reached with pure css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $("#slide").css("top", Math.max(180 - 0.2*window.scrollY, 0) + "px");
    $("#static").css("opacity", Math.max(1 - 0.004*window.scrollY, 0));
})
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dzket0tj/8/) is the updated Fiddle.

I would of course recommend changing the functions if you dont like the linear transitions.

Comment: Oh, that is awesome. Thank you very much . (>^^)>